# object.ReferenceEquals or == operator?

Tags: c#, linq, equals, throw

Why is `ThrowIfNull` implemented as:

```
    static void ThrowIfNull<T>(this T argument, string name) where T : class
    {
        if (argument == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
        }
    }
```

Wouldn't it be better rewritten as:

```
    static void ThrowIfNull<T>(this T argument, string name) where T : class
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(argument, null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
        }
    }
```

Pros: it helps avoiding confusing `Equals` overloads and probably makes the code more clear.

Any cons to that? There should be some.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no difference between the two. You're confusing *overriding* `Equals` (which isn't called in either implementation) with *overloading* `==` (which won't be relevant in either snippet as overloading is performed at compile time, and the compiler doesn't know enough about `T` to use any specific overload).

Just to show what I mean:

```
static void ThrowIfFoo<T>(this T argument, string name) where T : class
{
    if (argument == "foo")
    {
        throw new Exception("You passed in foo!");
    }
}
```

Testing with:

```
"foo".ThrowIfFoo(); // Throws

string x = "f";
x += "oo"; // Ensure it's actually a different reference

x.ThrowIfFoo(); // Doesn't throw
```

`ThrowIfFoo` doesn't know that `T` will be a string - because that depends on the *calling* code - and the overload resolution is only performed *when `ThrowIfFoo` is compiled*. Therefore it's using the operator `==(object, object)` rather than `==(string, string)`.

In other words, it's like this:

```
object foo1 = "foo";

string tmp = "f";
object foo2 = tmp + "oo";

Console.WriteLine(foo1.Equals(foo2)); // Prints True
Console.WriteLine(foo1 == foo2); // Prints false
Console.WriteLine((string) foo1 == (string) foo2); // Prints True
```

In the last line, the compiler knows it can use the overload of == because both operands have *compile-time* types of `string`.

Comment: ah, yes. that's what C# In-Depth Generics chapter told me, but I didn't listen!

Comment: @Grozz: Yeah, that guy thinks just like me ;)

Comment: @Jon Skeet, 
But when u debug the code, the second time X.ThrowIfFoo() actually says the x value as foo and not some thing plus even the getType on it says its a string than an object. I did this inside the extension method to check its type and stuffs. So i dont understand why second time though its "foo"=="foo" but still its false?

Comment: @zenwalker: The value is *equal* to "foo", but there are two different strings involved, so the reference comparison returns false. Will edit answer to show an example.

Comment: K if we use Equals, then both throws. So i got it. Thanks Jon

Comment: Yes @jon. its great explanation. The only thing is that I think I can address == is actually comparing references here. If you directly pass "Foo" here, the compiler optimization (might) point to same object, that means both foo actually points to the same location. On the other hand if we call string "f" + "oo" the reference differs. What do you think jon?

Comment: Oh.. I think I am late in asking this :)

Comment: @Jon..In your second line "overloading is performed at execution time".It should at compile time right ?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, don't you meet at JIT time and not execution time?

Comment: @Jonathan: No, I meant at C# compile time - the JIT compiler definitely doesn't do overload resolution.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I had the same gripe as Ashley :).

Answer (score 5):

The `==` operator is resolved at compile-time, not runtime, and since `T` is generic the compiler will use the implementation of `==` provided by `object` itself, which checks for reference equality.

This is exactly what `object.ReferenceEquals` does too: calls the `==` implementation provided by `object`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a mostly cosmetics.

`obj == null` will do a reference check and return, so will `Equals` if the argument is null and it's not overriden in `T`. It would require a pretty wonky/malicious implementation to return true when one argument is null.

Comment: would overloaded `Equals` do that?